# My output is not getting sorted in Mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am extracting records by joining multiple tables in mysql but the result is not getting sorted even though `order by` is used.

```
SELECT Company_name
FROM companyAboutData INNER JOIN (
  compAnalysisData INNER JOIN NIFTY_50
    ON compAnalysisData.ISIN = NIFTY_50.ISIN) 
ON companyAboutData.ISIN = NIFTY_50.ISIN
ORDER BY 'Company_name'
```

[image: Unsorted output]

Comment: Remove the quotes around 'Company_name' at your ORDER BY clause. Use `ORDER BY Company_name`

Comment: MySQL does allow the use of the "back tick" character (`) around field names but the single quote (') is for strings.

Comment: The issue in now resolved, there was a problem with data in the field which was being sorted, when it was corrected the sorting is working correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query, you have specified the column name as a string literal `'Company_name'`. Instead, you should use the column name without quotes, like this:

```
SELECT Company_name 
FROM companyAboutData 
INNER JOIN (compAnalysisData 
INNER JOIN NIFTY_50 
ON compAnalysisData.ISIN = NIFTY_50.ISIN) 
ON companyAboutData.ISIN = NIFTY_50.ISIN 
ORDER BY Company_name
```

Also, make sure that the column name is spelled correctly and that it belongs to the correct table. If the issue still persists, you may want to check the data type of the column and ensure that it is compatible with the `ORDER BY` clause.